# How to properly inject a dependency in Angular module in Web API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a **objectFactory.js** file:

```
(function () {
    var objectiveFactory = function ($http, $ngAnimate) {
        debugger;
        return {
            getObjectives: function () {                
                return $http.get('/api/Objective/');
            }
        };

    };
    debugger;
    try {
        //objectiveFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$ngAnimate'];// not working
        objectiveFactory.$inject = ['$http'];// perfectly works!
        angular.module('app', []).factory('objectiveFactory', objectiveFactory);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        var e1 = e;
    }

}());
```

It is really weird, however if I add new dependency `ngAnimate`:

```
objectiveFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$ngAnimate'];// not working
```

Then I've got an error:

> angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   ngAnimateProvider <- ngAnimate <- objectiveFactory
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=ngAnimateProvider%20%3C-%20ngAnimate%20%3C-%20objectiveFactory
>       at angular.js:68
>       at angular.js:4511
>       at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4664)
>       at angular.js:4516
>       at getService (angular.js:4664)
>       at injectionArgs (angular.js:4688)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4710)
>       at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4557)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4718)
>       at angular.js:4517

**But `'$http'`injecion perfectly works.**

I've explored a lot of info and double checked the following advices in my Web API application:

1. I've checked versions `angular'js` file and `angular-animate.js` and they are the same 1.5.8.
2. I've excluded minification and bundling, so files are loaded like the following code snippet:

   ```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular.js")"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-route.js")"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-animate.js")"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/objectiveFactory.js")"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/objective.js")"></script>
   ```

However, the error is the same:

> angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:

Does anybody know what I've done wrong? (`'$http'`injecion perfectly works)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11965

Comment: @raina77ow sorry, but how have you known that it is module name, not the service? As Dan Wahnlin injects like I've tried:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/angularjs-animations-in-version-1-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngAnimate` is the module name and you should inject `ngAnimate` in your main module. `angular.module('app', [])` here is your main module:

```
angular.module('app', [$ngAnimate']).factory('objectiveFactory', objectiveFactory);
```

Comment: sorry, I've forgotten about this way. However, if I write with `$ngAnimate`, then the error is the same.

Comment: Not `$ngAnimate`, plain `$animate`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've reall worked with that approximately 5 hours! I'll mark it up in 1 minute.

Comment: sorry, but how have you known that it is module name, not the service? As Dan Wahnlin injects like I've tried:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/angularjs-animations-in-version-1-2